# How can I handle infinite for loops in a recursive function with Stacks?

Tags: c#, selenium, recursion, stack, infinite-loop

So I'm in the process of creating a `BaseIFrame` Class to generically parse nested iFrames from any page without utilizing IDs, xpaths or anything DOM specific. I used recursion to catch all iFrames on a page and stacks to collect them. However, after debugging I discovered my recursive function loops over the same web element over and over before I hit a stack overflow.

How can I rectify this?

`BaseIFrame`  class:

```
namespace [Confidental namespace] {
 public class BaseIFrame {
         protected IWebDriver _driver;

         private ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> _iframes;

 public BaseIFrame(IWebDriver _driver) { 
        this._driver = _driver;     
         
        _iframes = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"));             
        _iframesSize = _iframes.Count();             
     }

 public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> getFrames() {
            return _iframes;
        }         

private static IEnumerable GetAllFramesRecursive<T>(IWebElement frame, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            var result = new Stack<IWebElement>();
            BaseIFrame baseClass = new BaseIFrame(driver);

            var iFrameList = baseClass._iframes;
            foreach (var i in iFrameList)
            {
                result.Push(i);

                foreach (IWebElement e in GetAllFramesRecursive<IWebElement>(i, driver))
                {
                    result.Push(e);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Public callable method for unit test
        public void GetAlliFramesRecursivePublic<T>(IWebElement test, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            GetAllFramesRecursive<IWebElement>(test, driver);
        }
    }
}
```

`BaseIFrameTest` class:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void AssertiFrameLength()
        {
            Login();

            var expected = 0;

            BaseIFrame bif = new BaseIFrame(_driver);
            bif.GetAlliFramesRecursivePublic<IWebElement>(bif.getFrames()[0], _driver);

            var elementSize = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("*")).Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < elementSize; i++)
            {
                var iframesSize = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame")).Count;
                expected += iframesSize;
            }

            var actual = bif.getFrames();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Count);
        }
```

Comment: Your for loop is always pushing values in stack and there is no condition to terminate the process or pop the stack which cause recursive function to run infinity

Comment: Thank you for the response. Shall I enter a break statement after the for loop?

Comment: I'd have thought that this line `baseClass._iframes` would have accessed the current frame and not the baseClass to access the inner frames. Otherwise you are always adding the same content and never reaching a place where `iFrameList` is empty

Comment: Well, I figured my first foreach loop would have looped through all outer frames, while my second foreach loop would have looped through all inner frames within the outer frames.

Comment: Sure, but as far as I can see, the inner loop calls the function again and reitterates over the outer frames again.

Answer (score 0):

A basic depth first iterator of a tree would look something like this:

```
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(rootItem);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            // Process the current item
            foreach (var child in current.ChildItems)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
```

If there is a risk that a node occurs multiple times (i.e. it is a graph rather than a tree) you need some way to avoid repeated visits, for example using a hashSet:

```
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(rootItem);
        var visited = new HashSet<T>();
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            if (visited.Add(current))
            {
                // Process the current item
                foreach (var child in current.ChildItems)
                {
                    stack.Push(child);
                }
            }
        }
```

Using iteration instead of recursion both avoids problems with stackOverflows, and you avoid the need to create a new collection for each node in the tree. In my examples you can simply do a `yield return current` as the process step to produce an iterator that is lazily evaluated. Replace `current.ChildItems` with whatever you need to generate the edges/children for the current node.

One thing that looks odd in your example is that I cannot see where the `frame` parameter is used. Only the `driver` seem to be used to generate the list of iFrames, but the driver seem to be the same in every invocation.